# deserialize xml element as string

Tags: c#, xml

I have this xml

```
<Report Name="Report">
  <Input>
    <Content>
      <XmlInput>Any xml inside the input tag should be deserialised as string</XmlInput>
      <XmlInput>Any xml inside the input tag should be deserialised as string</XmlInput>
    </Content>
    <!--<XmlInput>Any xml inside the input tag should be deserialised as string</XmlInput>-->
  </Input>
</Report>
```

and this class

```
[XmlRoot("Report")]
public class  Report
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Input Input { get; set; }
}

public class Input
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

I am using the following code to deserialize the xml

```
        string path = @"C:\temp\myxml.xml";
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Report));
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            var report = (Report)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
```

The problem here is, I want the xml content inside the content element to be deserialized as a string. Is this possible?

```
 <Content>
  <XmlInput>Any xml inside the input tag should be deserialised as string</XmlInput>
  <XmlInput>Any xml inside the input tag should be deserialised as string</XmlInput>
</Content>
```

Comment: So you want the two values in the two `XmlInput` elements concatenated and put in the `Input.Content` string?  Or do you want the string to be the inner xml of the `Content` element?  Either way you'll probably have to do custom serialization and deserialization.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to extract `<XmlInput>Any xml inside the input tag should be deserialised as string</XmlInput><XmlInput>Any xml inside the input tag should be deserialised as string</XmlInput>` as the result in your example?

Comment: @EsotericScreenName yes. so the string will contain the xml

Comment: You could deserialize each `XmlInput` like normal and add code to the `Input` class that would recreate the inner xml instead.

Comment: @juharr, actually this is just an example. the content element can basically include any xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doubt there's a way with deserialization... With Linq to XML it would look like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");

        IEnumerable<XElement> reportElements = doc.Descendants("Report");

        IEnumerable<Report> reports = reportElements
            .Select(e => new Report 
            { 
                Name = e.Attribute("Name").Value,
                Input = new Input
                {
                    Content = e.Element("Input").Element("Content").ToString()
                }
            });
    }
}
```

**Edit**

If you want to strip the content tag too:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");

        IEnumerable<XElement> reportElements = doc.Descendants("Report");

        IEnumerable<Report> reports = reportElements
            .Select(e => new Report
            {
                Name = e.Attribute("Name").Value,
                Input = new Input
                {
                    Content = string.Join("\n", e.Element("Input").Element("Content").Elements().Select(c => c.ToString()))
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Florian, didnt realise we could use linq to xml. Actually I can work with the example you provided. thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of trial and error, I was able to achieve this.

To clarify, given the following xml,

```xml
<Report Name="Report">
  <Input>
    <Content>
      <XmlInput>Any xml inside the input tag should be deserialised as string</XmlInput>
      <XmlInput>Any xml inside the input tag should be deserialised as string</XmlInput>
    </Content>
    <!--<XmlInput>Any xml inside the input tag should be deserialised as string</XmlInput>-->
  </Input>
</Report>
```

I need the following string extracted:

```cs
var content = "<Content><XmlInput>Any xml inside the input tag should be deserialised as string</XmlInput><XmlInput>Any xml inside the input tag should be deserialised as string</XmlInput></Content>";
```

**The Solution :**
Model your class like so:

```cs
[XmlRoot("Report")]
public class  Report
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Input Input { get; set; }
}

public class Input
{
    [XmlAnyElement("Content")]//use this attribute
    public XmlNode Content { get; set; }//use this type
}
```

After deserialization you will be able to access the string using the following navigation:

```cs
var result = reports.Input.Content.OuterXml;
```